# ASP.NET Core API and Angular build with one line of code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm making my first project with Angular and ASP.NET Core WEB Api backend. Is there a way to build both with one command line instead of building both of them separately ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use SPA template while creating your Asp.Net core web application